# Better way to initialize UIImageView with non-zero origin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

Creating UIImageView with some offset is quite common task when you're building interface in code.
I can see two ways to initialize UIImageView with origin not equal to (0,0):

First way requires only image filename and origin, but contains a lot of code (we can reduce number of lines by one using `frame.origin = CGPointMake(x,y);` ):

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_filename"]];
CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
frame.origin.x = 150;
frame.origin.y = 100;
undoBg.frame = frame;
```

Second way has much less code, looks cleaner but we need to hardcode image size:

```
UIImageView *shadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 800, 600)];
shadowView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_filename"];
```

What is best practice for you and why?
Thanks.

Comment: Are all of your images going to be the exact same size as the UIImageView frames? You need to hardcode all of the image sizes, what about the origin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hardcoding the images sizes is a form of [Unnamed numerical constants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) which is an indication of [Code Smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)

This sort of thing should be avoided as much as possible as it can generate code that is a lot harder to maintain and is prone to human introduced errors.  For example what happens when your graphic artist changes the size of the image?  Instead of changing just one thing (the image) you now have to change many things (the image, and every place in the code where the image size has been hard coded)

Remember that you code not for today, but for the people who will come after you and maintain your code.

If anything, if you were really concerned about the extra lines of code, then you would abstract loading the UIImageView into a category, so that it can be used everywhere (note that this code is not tested):

```
@interface UIImageView (MyExtension)
-(UIImageView*)myLoadImage:(NSString*)named at:(CGPoint)location;
@end

@implementation
-(UIImageView*)myLoadImage:(NSString*)named at:(CGPoint)location
{
  UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:named]];
  CGRect frame = imgView.frame;
  frame.origin.x = location.x;
  frame.origin.y = location.y;
  return imgView;
}
@end
```

Then you could simply do:

```
UIImageView* imageView = [UIImageView myLoadImage:@"image_filename" at:CGPointMake(150,100)];
```

Comment: Pater, I agree with you that it is better to have as less hardcoded stuff as possible. However we'll still have hardcoded origin. And this thing should be hardcoded. I basically don't see any other way to place UIImageView to the right place. In case if graphics is changed (e.g. resolution is changed) origin will be changed too. So we still need to go through hardcoded stuff (yes, twice less hardcoded stuff).

Comment: I just wanted to add that [shadowView sizeToFit]; will make the dimensions of the UIImageView match the dimensions of the image itself. I'm still not sure when you say you need to hard code the sizes that you mean all of the images are different sizes or not.

Comment: @OgreSwamp as for the location being hard coded, yeah you are stuck with that.  Unless you define a single origin for all your graphics and then build the locations of all the images programmatically from that origin and offsets to various locations.  Of course you will never be able to build a completely device independent UI that flows nicely no matter what the asset sizes are.  And the more you try to do so, then the more work it will take.

Comment: @OgreSwamp you want to tell a graphic designer that the image he spent hours and hours laboring over to get just that perfect size is going to be squished into a fixed rectangle .. lol ..  But its horses for courses (and the designer should have known what the asset size was in the first place).

Comment: I'm not sure why do you think I'm going to squeeze something, but I've got your point :) 
BTW, what do you thinking about storing origins as #define in separated header file? I'm talking about situation when you have >10 views in one view controller with fixed origins.

Comment: @OgreSwamp  Defines in one location can be a good idea, but I lean towards static const vars as they are symbols you can inspect

Answer (score 1):

I use the second one with slight modification,

```
UIImageView *shadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 150, 800, 600)];
shadowView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension]  ];
```

because imageNamed: caches image and cause memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I usually want my code to be easily readable. On the other hand I want the job done as fast as possible. In this case, there is so little code, I would go with less code. This is because I can get understand it so fast anyways. If it would be a much bigger example, I would use the easily readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it depends on your requirements. If I need to create an imageView in a class where the offset may change then I might do something like:

```
int myX = 10;
int myY = 100;
int myWidth = 200;
int myHeight = 300;

UIImageView *shadowView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myX, myY, myWidth, myHeight)];
shadowView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_filename"];
```

but if I don't need to vary the offset and I know for a fact that the value won't change and no-one else will be needing to read or re-use my code then there's maybe nothing wrong (imho) with just using numbers in place of the int vars.

btw, you might want to avoid imageNamed as it caches the image which can lead to leaks.

Comment: as far as I know `imageNamed` caches image, not `initWithImage`

Comment: doh! copy and paste error, you are right. edited above to avoid confusion for others reading my answer.